# Jinja2 puts layout's head + unwanted break in child's body

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I recently started using flask/python but I seem to have a problem with Jinja2 that I can't resolve on my own. I have a layout.html template like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Some Title</title>
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 800px)' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style_mobile.css') }}" />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1200px)' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style_middle.css') }}" />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 1200px)' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style_desktop.css') }}" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>Some header</div>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  <div>Some footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And a number of child templates extending the layout like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-wrapper">
Here be content.
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I went to one of my child pages in my browser, I expected to see a full copy of my layout template, including the same head with only the content of the child added at the right place. Instead, I got:

```
<head>
some chrome extensions
</head>
<body>
"&#65279;


"
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Some Title</title>
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 800px)' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style_mobile.css') }}" />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1200px)' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style_middle.css') }}" />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 1200px)' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style_desktop.css') }}" />
<div>Some header</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
Here be content.
</div>
<div>Some footer</div>
```

So the layout template is extended with the content of the child alright, but the content of the head is in the body and there is an unwanted break at the top of the page, pushing the layout down. When I click source in my Chrome browser though (as opposed to elements), it shows the code of the child template extended in the layout template just as it is supposed to be... I can't seem to wrap my head around this. How do I resolve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've copied the code you provided into a basic flask application to try and reproduce the error but I'm unable to and the template renders as expected. Can you try a different browser and see if you get the same issue, I'm wondering if there's a chrome extension causing the issue?

Comment: How are you rendering the template?

Comment: @AnthonyBlackshaw: The same thing happens in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: `&#65279;` is a non-breaking space.  Might want to check for that in your original code (it's not showing up in what you have here).

Comment: @SeanVieira: It is not showing up because it is not in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem. It had something to do with BOM (byte order mark).
Saving my files in a text editor with 'add BOM tag to file' disabled got rid of the &#65279; at the beginning of the page. The contents of the head tag are left alone now as well.

Comment: I had the same issue, but had trouble saving the file without the BOM tag. My solution was to copy the entire HTML document's contents and paste them into a new document. Problem solved!

Comment: Thanks I was going crazy.